# How to set Text to a property from another class in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

hey all so I'm trying to set a Text to a value from another property from a different class in flutter
so I have two files

First one is

chatPage.dart

```
    class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _ChatPageState createState() => _ChatPageState();
    }
    
    class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
      List<ChatUsers> chatUsers = [
        ChatUsers(name: "Jane Russel", messageText: "Awesome Setup", imageURL: "images/userImage1.jpeg", time: "Now"),
        ChatUsers(name: "Glady's Murphy", messageText: "That's Great", imageURL: "images/userImage2.jpeg", time: "Yesterday"),
        ChatUsers(name: "Jorge Henry", messageText: "Hey where are you?", imageURL: "images/userImage3.jpeg", time: "31 Mar"),
        ChatUsers(name: "Philip Fox", messageText: "Busy! Call me in 20 mins", imageURL: "images/userImage4.jpeg", time: "28 Mar"),
        ChatUsers(name: "Debra Hawkins", messageText: "Thankyou, It's awesome", imageURL: "images/userImage5.jpeg", time: "23 Mar"),
        ChatUsers(name: "Jacob Pena", messageText: "will update you in evening", imageURL: "images/userImage6.jpeg", time: "17 Mar"),
        ChatUsers(name: "Andrey Jones", messageText: "Can you please share the file?", imageURL: "images/userImage7.jpeg", time: "24 Feb"),
        ChatUsers(name: "John Wick", messageText: "How are you?", imageURL: "images/userImage8.jpeg", time: "18 Feb"),
      ];
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SafeArea(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16,right: 16,top: 10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Conversations",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8,right: 8,top: 2,bottom: 2),
                      height: 30,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        color: Colors.pink[50],
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.pink,size: 20,),
                          SizedBox(width: 2,),
                          Text("Add New",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16,left: 16,right: 16),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Search...",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.grey.shade600, size: 20,),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade100
                      )
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: chatUsers.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return ConversationList(
                  name: chatUsers[index].name,
                  messageText: chatUsers[index].messageText,
                  imageUrl: chatUsers[index].imageURL,
                  time: chatUsers[index].time,
                  isMessageRead: (index == 0 || index == 3)?true:false,
                );
              },
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And i have another file called
chatDetailPage.dart

```
class ChatDetailPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _ChatDetailPageState createState() => _ChatDetailPageState();
}

class _ChatDetailPageState extends State<ChatDetailPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int i=0;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back,color: Colors.black,),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 2,),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage("<https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/5.jpg>"),
                    maxRadius: 20,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 12,),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('User',style: TextStyle( fontSize: 16 ,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),),
                        SizedBox(height: 6,),
                        Text("Online",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600, fontSize: 13),),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.settings,color: Colors.black54,),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container()
    );
  }
}
```

Im trying to set the text value from the appBar in the chatDetail.dart page from the existing 'User' to the name value from ConversationList().

does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to send data from one page to another?

Comment: in the chatPage.dart there is a list made from class chatUsers, im trying to set the Text in the app bar in the chatDetailPage.dart into the ChatUsers.name property

Comment: If you want to set `ChatUsers.name` from `ChatPage.dart` then you have to pass the parameter to your `ChatDetailPage.dart`. And as I can see there is no routing from your `ChatPage.dart` to `ChatDetailPage.dart` then how can you set the data of one screen to another one.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in this way

```
class ChatDetailPage extends StatefulWidget{
  ChatDetailPage({this.chatuser}); 
  ChatUsers chatuser = ChatUsers();
  @override
  _ChatDetailPageState createState() => _ChatDetailPageState();
}
```

then in your build method, you should call it this way

```
Text(widget.chatuser.name);
```

and you should call ChatDetailPage in this way

```
ChatDetailPage(chatuser:chatUsers[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the import the chatPage.dart file into the chatDetails.dart file?
If you didn't, you should import the chatPage.dart file into the chatDetails.dart file first, before you can access to properties of the chatPage.dart Class from the chatDetails.dart file.